Proving Non-Simplicity of Groups of Order $p^2q^n$ with $p < q$ Primes
I want to prove that if $p < q$ are two primes, then a group of order $p^2q^n$ ($n \geq 1$) is not simple.
I understand that the problem needs to be split into two cases:

$n = 1$
$n > 1$

For the case where $n = 1$, I think I know how to prove the result by considering the Sylow $p$-subgroups and Sylow $q$-subgroups. However, I am unsure how to proceed for the case $n > 1$.
Could someone help me understand how to approach the proof for $n > 1$? Any hints or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I don’t remember it but doesn’t it rely on the fact that all syllows are conjugated and then you probably can show that there is only one. Now it remains to chose wether you study p ou q syllows

I couldn't really make progress this way.

Could you show your progress and maybe state the condition on the number of respectively $p$ and $q$-syllows ?

Here's my approach. Let $Q\in\text{Syl}_q(G)$ and consider $m=|G:\textbf N_G(Q)|$. Then $m\in\{1,p,p^2\}$. If $m=1$ then $Q\unlhd G$. If $m=p$ then the index of $\textbf{N}_G(Q)$ in $G$ is the minimum prime which divides the order of $G$, and hence $\textbf{N}_G(Q)\unlhd G$. In this case, $Q\unlhd G$ as $Q\text{ char }\textbf{N}_G(Q)\unlhd G$. Then we may assume that $m=p^2$.
Suppose first that $n=1$. Since $m$ is the number of distinct $G$-conjugates of $Q$, then $G$ has $p^2(q-1)$ elements of order $q$. Also, $G$ has at least $p^2-1$ elements of $p$-power order. Then $G$ has at least $p^2(q-1)+(p^2-1)+1=p^2q$ elements. Then necessarily $G$ has $p^2-1$ elements of $p$-power order and hence there is only one Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, which is normal.
Now we suppose that $n>1$. Since $|G:\textbf N_G(Q)|\equiv1\text{ (mod } q)$ then $q$ divides $p^2-1$, and since $p<q$ then $q$ divides $p+1$. Then necessarily $q=p+1$ and $p=2$, $q=3$. This implies that $\text{Core}_G(Q)\not=1$. In other case, by Cayley's theorem $|G|$ must divide $|G:Q|!=4!=2\cdot3\cdot4$, but this is not possible as $3^2$ divides $|G|$.
